# jquery autocomplete color change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I am using bootstrap for UI and jquery custome UI for autocomplete. When suggested items are listed, i would like to match bootstratp blue color instead of yellow. Where can I chnage the color and what is the correct hex ? Please see the attched image. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead` as it's part of bootstrap?

Comment: I love to d othat. Infact I tried. Please see my other post. I am very new to bootstrap and jquery. I sepnd significant amout of time to make jquery autocomeplet work with ajax call. I tried if i can get som ehelp to convert it to typehead but gave up. Pleas esee my othe rpost. If you can help on in, I teally want to use type head.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750535/converting-to-typehead. BTW, I am using bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.ui-state-hover {
    background: #428BCA!important;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/DLLVw/104/

Comment: @user3067524 Please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a loot of tries, I found a working code for myself. After reading the entire jquery UI CSS file I found that **#c77405** was the colour responsible for this orange effect. You can use notepad++ for finding all occurrences of this colour.you can copy and paste the following code in your file as internal CSS.

```
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #5b518b; /* any color you like */

}
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
    color: #5b518b; /* any color you like */
}
```

Comment: The second class helps me to style Jquery UI Autocomplete selection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
    background: #6693bc !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```