# Changing Jquery ui autocomplete result that contains specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a very similar question here: 
[jquery autocomplete color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803295/jquery-autocomplete-color-change)

Which is essentially what I want to do but I want to change the css if one of the search results contains the word "Entry".

This is the function im calling using the jquery ui script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".wholesale_product_id").autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/ingredients-sheets/search-3hou5njk3jndnjk3kj2.php",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

This function is working and will produce a list like this (please note I have copied the html from dev tools and just copied part of it for demonstration purposes) :

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 1110px; top: 322px; left: 469px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-2" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">[*2042*] - Fanta Orange cans 355ml x 24</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">[*116*] - Fanta Strawberry cans 355ml x 24</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">[*4381*] - Fanta Berry cans 355ml x 24</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-44" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Entry ID - [*2115*] - Fanta Strawberry cans 355ml x 24 (no full stop)</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A picture of the results in the browser:

[Search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCATl.jpg)

**What I want to achieve:**

I want any search result or  tag that contains "Entry ID" or "Entry" to be red colored text and preferably at the top of the list.

**I have tried:**

Just to see if I could change the colour to all the search results using the following code but even that doesn't work and thats without trying to find the string Entry.

```
$( "a.ui-menu-item").css( "color", "#e74c3c");
```

Any advice would be great.

*** EDIT ***

Just a bit more information, the results that start with Entry ID are custom results we have saved that come from a different database table and we want these to be at the top of the search result list with a red font color.

Comment: leaving these here [1](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-ui-matched-text-color) [2](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/b4atwkch/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have complete control over how AutoComplete renders it's list with `_renderItem`
If you like to do it **server side**, just return the Json list with an `IsRedClass` property and the name

```
$(".wholesale_product_id").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/ingredients-sheets/search-3hou5njk3jndnjk3kj2.php",
    minLength: 1
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append('<a class="' + item.IsRedClass + '">' + item.Name + '</a>')
      .appendTo(ul);
};
```

**Or client side:**

```
$(".wholesale_product_id").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/ingredients-sheets/search-3hou5njk3jndnjk3kj2.php",
    minLength: 1
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append('<a class="' + item.Name.includes("Entry") ? "red" : "" + '">' + item.Name + '</a>')
      .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you this makes sense, may I ask though how would I apply that to only <a> tags that contain the string "Entry"? I can see how this would work but I need only results that contain the word entry to be red.  Thank you very much for your answer as its a massive help, been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: would I just need to check the "item" parameter passed through to see if that contains the string Entry and then if that returns true apply the format changes?

Comment: I've added an example to do it client side. Autocomplete it's very powerful, this is just an example, but you can do it all sort of things